# Can the same person play all matches in the Fed Cup?

Tags: tennis

I know that a team from a country consists of max 4 players. Of the total 4 singles matches played at the Cup, I've always observed that a single player only plays in at most 2 matches. I was wondering whether it was due to any regulation?

Answer (score 1):

No, she can't. The regulations can be found on [this page](https://www.fedcup.com/en/organisation/rules-regulations.aspx), and rule 32(b) in the [PDF](https://www.fedcup.com/media/299243/299243.pdf) says:

> In  singles,  each  team  shall  consist  of  two  players,  who  shall each play against  each  of  the  opposing  team to  the  best  of three  tie-break sets.